# Pass (comma separated) -yet single parameter to cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursors

I have to get selection for a given string (with comma separated values) passed to the cursor. There can be multiple values that could be passed via single variable. My code is somewhat like:

```
CURSOR My_Cursor( vsStr1 )
  IS
  SELECT some_field
    FROM some_table
   WHERE txtfield1 IN ( vsStr1 );    --this field is varchar2 type

vsStr1 varchar2(100) := '01, 25, 80, 100';
```

How to pass that variable correclty? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version? Anyway, this'll do what you want: https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/plsql-new-features-and-enhancements-11gr1#dynamic_sql_enhancements

Comment: The IN clause expects a list of values, but vsStr1 is just one value - a string of comma separated numbers, not a list of multiple values. You need to use Dynamic SQL probably (create the sql in a string, add the proper values as a string and then compile the full statement)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest little dirty trick I know for this is `xmltable()`. With `xmltable()`you can convert a comma-seperated list of values into rows, for example:

```
select * from xmltable('1, 2, 3')

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
1
2
3
```

Notice how the column is named `column_value` automatically. This is an `XMLType` column, that you need to convert to be able to compare it with  your regular types, for example `(column_value).getnumberval()` or `(column_value).getstringval()`

Now using this, a cursor could be coded like this:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  l_parameters varchar2(50) := '101, 102, 103, 104';

  cursor my_cursor (params varchar2)
  is
  select employee_id, first_name, last_name from hr.employees
  where employee_id in
    (select (column_value).getnumberval() from xmltable(params));
begin
  for c in my_cursor(l_parameters) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(c.employee_id || ': ' || c.first_name || ', ' || c.last_name);
  end loop;
end;
/

101: Neena, Kochhar
102: Lex, De Haan
103: Alexander, Hunold
104: Bruce, Ernst
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using subquery factoring, regular expressions, and a hierarchical query on dual.

```
CURSOR My_Cursor( vsStr1 ) IS
   WITH 
      RawInputData As (
         SELECT vsStr1 sStr1 FROM dual
         ),
      InputData As (
         SELECT regexp_substr((SELECT sStr1 FROM RawInputData),'[^,]+',1,level) CurrentsStr1 
         FROM dual 
         CONNECT BY level <= length((SELECT sStr1 FROM RawInputData)) 
            - length(replace((SELECT sStr1 FROM RawInputData),',',''))+1
      )  
   SELECT some_field
   FROM some_table
   WHERE txtfield1 IN ( SELECT CurrentsStr1 FROM InputData );

vsStr1 varchar2(100) := '01,25,80,100';
```